# Validating Configuration in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a section in appsettings.json which contains a list of libraries and their dependencies, and how to configure them in different execution environments.I'd like to be able to validate that the library collection includes all the dependencies.

That's easy enough to do with a little recursion. But I can't figure out how to override the configuration binding process so that I can do the validation.

The only way I've come up with is to create a raw collection of the libraries, based on appconfig.json, and then create a service which validates the collection and makes it available. Something like:

```
public class RawLibraries : List<Library>
{
}

public class LibraryResolver
{
    public LibraryResolver( IOptions<RawLibraries> rawLibs, ILogger logger )
    {
        // validate rawLibs and log errors
    }
    // ...implementation
}

services.Configure<RawLibraries>(Configuration.GetSection("Libraries"));

services.AddSingleton<LibraryResolver, LibraryResolver>();
```

But this seems convoluted. Thoughts on a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to follow the authors and write your own extension method with additional validation?

Take a look here. This is the source code of `services.Configure<>` method:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Extension methods for adding options services to the DI container.
  /// </summary>
  public static class OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions
  {
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers an action used to configure a particular type of options.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TOptions">The options type to be configured.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection" /> to add the services to.</param>
    /// <param name="configureOptions">The action used to configure the options.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection" /> so that additional calls can be chained.</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TOptions> configureOptions) where TOptions : class
    {
      if (services == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("services");
      if (configureOptions == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("configureOptions");
      services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>>((IConfigureOptions<TOptions>) new ConfigureOptions<TOptions>(configureOptions));
      return services;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see `Configure<TOptions>` method is an extension method. Simply write your own let say `ConfigureAndValidate<TOptions>()` extension method which will do proper validation before `services.AddSingleton...` line.

Comment: My bad! I'm still getting used to being able to look under the hood about how all this stuff is put together. Thanx, David!